# Set ResultSetMetaDataOptions for a connection object in C3P0 connection pool datasource for Oracle db

Tags: oracle, database-connection, resultset, tablename

Has anybody been successful in retrieving the tablename from ResultSetMetaData via the getTableName() for Oracle database ?

All the online materials suggest to set ResultSetMetaDataOptions to "1", but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here [Information about getTableName()](http://fixunix.com/weblogic/223501-resultsetmetadata-gettablename-int-column-dont-work.html):

> Hi. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but Oracle's DBMS doesn't send
>   the information about what table a column came from, so the oracle
>   driver will never be able to implement that resultset metadata call.
>   Most DBMSes don't either, and so you will see that 99% of all JDBC
>   drivers will also not implement that call to return anything useful.
>   Only Sybase, with their very latest driver and a specific optional
>   DBMS configuration, have done it. It takes a change in the DBMS that
>   most DBMS vendors will never bother to do.

**Edit**: I tried below approach to set the parameter:

```java
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put ("user", "scott");
info.put ("password", "tiger");
info.put ("ResultSetMetaDataOptions", "1");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl", info);
```

However, it didn't work - I was still unable to get the table name. This property is not on the list of possible properties which you can check here: [Driver documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html). I was also unable to find any other way to set that property and get it to work.

Comment: When the ResultSetMetaDataOptions property is set to 1 and the ResultSetMetaData.getTableName() method is called, the table name information that is returned by the Oracle driver depends on whether the column in a result set maps to a column in a table in the database. For each column in a result set that maps to a column in a table in the database, the Oracle driver returns the table name associated with that column. For columns in a result set that do not map to a column in a table (for example, aggregates and literals), the Oracle driver returns an empty string.

Comment: I just want to know how i can set this information ResultSetMetaDataOptions ?!!

Comment: @KrithikaVittal I was unable to get the table name by setting this property to 1.

Comment: Yes I could not retrieve the table name at all @Przemyslaw Kruglej ... Thanks